# How to diagnose extremely slow AWS RDS MySQL Performance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

My DB has around 15 tables, each with 40 columns, with 10.000 rows each.
Most of it with VARCHAR, some indexes and foreign keys.

Sometime I need to reconstruct my database (design flaw, working on it), which takes about 40 seconds locally. Now I'm trying to do the same to a AWS RDS MySQL 5.75 instance, but it takes forever, something like 40-50 minutes. The last time I had to do this same process it took no more than 5 minutes, still way more than the local 40 seconds, but I'm happy with it.

My internet speed is at about 35 Mbps Download / 5 Mbps Upload.
I know it's not fast, but it's consistent, and it hasn't changed since my last rebuilt.

I enabled General Logs, but all I can see are the INSERT queries, occasionally some "SELECT 1".
I do have same space for improvements on my code, but still, from 00:40:00 to 50:00:00, it seems that there's something else going on.

Any ideas on how to diagnose and find the bottleneck?
Thanks

--

Additional relevant information:
It is a Micro instance from AWS, all of the relevant monitoring indicators are basically flat: CPU at 4%, Free Storage Space at 20.000 MB, Freeable Memory at 200 MB, Write IOPS at around 2,5, the server runs a 5.7.25 MySQL, 1vCPU, 1Gb of RAM and 20GB of SSD. This is the same as 3 months ago when I last rebuilt the database.

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`: https://pastebin.com/jSrAzYZP
`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES`: https://pastebin.com/YxD7dVhR
`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`: https://pastebin.com/r5wffB5t
`SHOW PROCESS LIST`: https://pastebin.com/kWwiyGwf
`SELECT * FROM information_schema...`: https://pastebin.com/eXGBmetP

I haven't made any big changes to the server configuration, except enabling logs, e maxing out `max_allowed_packets` and saving logs to file.

In my backend I have a Flask app running, when it receives the API call, it takes a bunch of pickled objects and adds them all to the database (appending the Flask SQLAlchemy class to a list) and then running `db.session.add_all(entries)`, trying to run a bulk operation. The code is the same, both for `localhost` and my remote server.

It does get slower in three specific tables, most of them with VARCHAR columns, but nothing different from my last inserts - it seems odd that the problem would be data, or the way the code is structured, or at least doesn't seem reasonable that this would result in a 20 second (localhost) to 40 minutes (hosted server) time, specially when the rest of the tables work mostly the same.

Comment: You're leaving out a _lot_ of information. Let's start with the RDS instance type: are you using one of the "burstable" instances? If yes, have you run out of CPU credits (you can go to the Monitoring page to check). What size EBS volume do you have, and are you running up against the peak IOPS for it? And lastly, how much free memory do you have? All available from the monitoring page.

Comment: Next, you need to describe what you mean by "reconstruct my database." Are you downloading all the tables and then inserting them again (that's the only case where your upload/download speed matters)? If yes, are you using bulk operations or single inserts in a loop (that will kill you on a remote connection). Or are you using SQL `insert-select` statements, which are performed on the database server?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for bottleneck relief.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, additional informations on the question.

Comment: @lowercase00 Could you post current, D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; to go with other data posted 20 hours ago?  Do you have access to Skype TALK?  We are in UTC -6 hours time zone.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, just posted the patebin, thanks!

Comment: Could we use Skype TALK to review A) SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST item SLEEP for 2525 seconds?  42 minutes.  B) buffer_pages_read 1473 to buffer_pages_written 187756 for every page read, 127 pages written.  C) since instance start, dml_inserts 1,933,529 rows inserted into tables. D) os_log_bytes_written 239, 418,368 since instance start.  E) com_flush rate of 13 times per hour?  Causes opened_tables churn.  F) com_rollback averaging every 98 seconds. G) handler_rollback (deadlocks?) averaging every 176 seconds. H) select_scan of tbl 1,505 times per hour. Need indexes. When could we talk?

Answer (score 4):

Enable the slow log, set long_query_time=0, run your code, then put the resulting log through mysqldumpslow.

Establish which queries contribute most to slowness and take it from there.

Compare the config between your old server and your new one.

Also, are they the same version of MySQL? 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0 can produce very different execution plans (with 5.6 usually coming up with the sane one if they differ).

Comment: Thanks. I had long query time set to 1, don't know why, mysqldumpslow is not working, byt when I see slow_query_log is basically empty, will try with zero. I don't have the config between the old and new. The funny thing is, is the same Database as 3-4 months ago, so can't understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your AWS RDS Parameters group

```
thread_cache_size=24  # from 8 to reduce threads_created count
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to enable more use of SSD IOPS capacity
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 512K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 21
query_cache_size=0  # from 1M since you have QC turned off with query_cache_typ=OFF
```

Determine why com_flush is running 13 times per hour and get it stopped to avoid table open thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after migrating to RDS all my database Indexes are gone! They weren't migrated along with the schema and data. Make sure you're indexes are there.
Also, MySQL query cache is OFF by default in RDS. This won't help the performance of your initial query, but it may speed things up in general.
You can set `query_cache_type` to 1 and define a value for `query_cache_size`. I also changed the `thread_cache_size` from 8 to 24 and `innodb_io_capacity` from 200 to 1900 don't know if it helps you.
Also creating AWS DB Parameter Groups helped me a lot with configuring and tuning DB variables. Here you can read more:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Comment: Hi! You mentioned that the indexes were gone after migrating. How did you fix that issue?